# Min-height not working on another server.

Tags: css, html

I'm creating a new page for one of my website. In the layout, the first section has to adapt the content to the middle of the screen depending on the screen size, and other section could be only of it's content height. It's working fine here: http://jilson.me/clickmeter/h4/

But when I used the same code for another server, it is not working. http://mvc4.9nl.com/
I'm sure it's not depending on the server. But definitely something is wrong and I can't figure it out why!

Here is a HTML and CSS code used for this section.

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center white iphone-jumbo-close first-top-section">
</div>


.vertical-center {
    min-height: 768px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font: 0px/0 a;
}
.vertical-center:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: That site is giving 20 different resources that couldn't be retrieved. Upon inspecting the element you're refering to, no styles have been found for it. Clearly the code you're showing here is not applied to the site, possibly because it is in one of the missing resources.

Comment: @gpgekko: The styles are showing while inspecting the elements and the resources are loading very well. But the same code works differently for different pages.

Comment: When I hide the `content: " ";` in `.vertical-center:before {` in the first site, I get the same effect as the second site. So probably the second site isn't reading this attribute well. Anyone know why it is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
.vertical-center {
    min-height: 768px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font: 0px/0 a;
    height: 100%;
}
```